# Why do I have two interfaces on my VM?

Tags: networking, network-interface, vagrant

For one of my projects,I cretead Vm with standard Vagrantfile,by defining private IP
[image]

Vagrantfile

```
hosts = {
"n1" => "192.168.77.10",
"n2" => "192.168.77.11",
"n3" => "192.168.77.12",
"n4" => "192.168.77.13"
}

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
# always use Vagrants insecure key
    config.ssh.insert_key = false
# forward ssh agent to easily ssh into the different machines
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    check_guest_additions = false
    functional_vboxsf = false
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"

    hosts.each do |name, ip|
     config.vm.define name do |machine|
      machine.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip
      machine.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
       v.name = name
      end
     end
    end
end
```

How it comes that I have enp0s3 and enp0s8 interfaces?

Comment: Could you share the relevant parts of the vagrantfile? According to [one page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23962699/4957508), this can happen if you repeat the `config.vm.network` definition.

Comment: It seems to me hat my loop is not repeating definition.